# Complex properties for Facebook objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a Facebook story "Complete a Level", where Level is my custom object that has custom property "chapter" of my type Chapter.
In the caption of my story I wrote

```
{level.title} of {level.chapter.title}
```

How to make the post request via the OpenGraph API to actually fill the chapter?

I'm trying to do that this way (JavaScript)

```
title: "Level #",
data: {
    chapter: {
        title: "my chapter"
    }
}
```

which doesn't work.

If my custom property would be of type String and caption would look like `{level.title} of {level.chapter}` and data would look like `data: {chapter: "my chapter"}` — it works. But I guess I should have a proper objects connection so that Facebook can output and group things nicely.

**Upd:** or shall I write caption like `{level.title} of {chapter.title}`? And how to pass data for that?

Comment: Have you tried the _Get Code_ button in your app dashboard?

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately "get code" gives absolutely irrelevant and general example=(